# (Cordova) Xcode 5.1 Error Apple Mach-O Linker error libCordova.a file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I recently tried to archive my product in order to submit it to the app store, but came across this error that has eaten up my time. The error goes as follows:

> Ld
>   /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Alter.build/App\
>   Store-iphoneos/Alter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Alter normal armv7
>       cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Alter/platforms/ios
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/BuildProductsPath/App\ Store-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/BuildProductsPath/App\ Store-iphoneos -filelist
>   /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Alter.build/App\
>   Store-iphoneos/Alter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Alter.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/BuildProductsPath/App\ Store-iphoneos/libCordova.a -ObjC
>   -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework AssetsLibrary
>   /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation
>   -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Alter.build/App\
>   Store-iphoneos/Alter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Alter_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App\
>   Store/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Alter.build/App\
>   Store-iphoneos/Alter.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Alter

This error also follows:

> ld: file not found:
>   /Users/guled/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Alter-arpezfgnfzcguefnjpllgwzddkld/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Alter-App
>   Store/BuildProductsPath/App Store-iphoneos/libCordova.a clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was driving me crazy for hours. Apps builds and runs fine. Cannot create archive. Cordova 3.5 and Xcode 5.1.1.

I was able to resolve this issue by using the solution in the comments from Somnibyte. I was creating a "Distribution" build configuration (like I always do), and I was unable to create an archive from this "Distribution" configuration. Spent hours tinkering and trying. I finally found the comment from Somnibyte, attempted to simply archive the "Release" build configuration instead, and... BAM! It worked! Thank you thank you thank you Somnibyte. Hope this saves someone else some time.

I think the issue may be here:

[image: CordovaLib.xcodeproj]

Comment: You are welcome my friend. I am very sorry for the late reply. I don't go on this site often (but now I really need to get some help from time to time). I'm glad I made someone happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually adding the libcordova.a file to the xcode project? Thats all I can think of, having no experience with cordova myself.

The error here seems to be that xcode is just failing to find the libcordova.a, so this link may help some.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: I definitely have the "libcordova.a" file inside my directory, I can see it, and I can access it through Xcode. When I look at my "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binary with Libraries" I clearly see "libcordova.a" and it's not red. What's odd was that once, when building my project with cordova (I repeatedly would remake the situation by making a new Xcode project), the file turned out red in those sections. It's really weird. I hope I can get this fixed.

Comment: It seems that when I "clean" the project the libcordova.a dependency listing turns red....

Comment: I just noticed that when I archive a "release" archive It worked perfectly. I remember watching a video on Youtube, I think they misled me, I'm not sure, but they told people to duplicate the schema, name it "App store" and then sign something, and then archive it. I decided to archive the project itself under "release" archive and it worked. Was I right or were they wrong?