# Error while Archiving a cordova project having watchkit + widget in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

```
ld: file not found: /Users/sherjeel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fjlpgteocryzzfddwihrjvhlezox/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So he's my Proejct structure:

```
iOS Project in Cordovoa
|
|
|
--- Project Files
|
|
|
--- Watch Kit
------ Watch Kit Extensionm
|
|
|
--- Widget
```

And I have integrated all the stuff one by one, so first created the project, then added a watch kit app, and lastly a widget.

So if I will remove a widget then it can archive else not.

Please help !!

I have tried one or two answers ([(Cordova) Xcode 5.1 Error Apple Mach-O Linker error libCordova.a file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256126/cordova-xcode-5-1-error-apple-mach-o-linker-error-libcordova-a-file-not-found)) which I found here, but none of them worked for me.

But yes, I can install and see the app on my iDevices. But archive is failed.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps in your each targets and you're good to go.

1. In your Target's Build Settings, find "Other Linker Flags"
2. Delete "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libCordova.a"
3. Change "-force_load" to "-all_load"